# iOS - How to let an UITextView be always above an UIImageView?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uiimageview, uitextview

I built an interface using Interface Builder. In part of that interface, there is a UIImageView with an image and a UITextView right above it. However, I can`t manage to put the UITextView above the UIImageView. The UIImageView always stays above the UITextView, making my text unreadable.

How can I fix this simple glitch?

Thank you in advance! =D

Comment: Have you tried to select the UIImageView and put it behind the UITextView by using the menu "Editor->Arrange->Send To Back"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By above it, I'm assuming you mean above it in the z-order of the subviews of your view.  Try selecting the view you want to manipulate, then click Editor -> Arrange -> Send Forward/Backward.

Comment: That fix partially. The problem is that I have 3 things: an UIImageVIew, an UITextView and a button. The button is set to "Custom" so it becomes invisible. What I need to do is to have the following hierarchy: UIImaveView -> UITextView -> Button. Your solution worked great for the UIImageVIew -> UITextView part, but when I put the Button above the UITextView now, it doesn`t respond to actions (instead the actions related to the UITextView is triggered, like it was the most foreground thing on the screen. I tried to set the button to sendForward as well but it didn`t work. Any other ideas?

Comment: At this point, it's getting pretty hacky and a little fragile so you may want to try to figure out your problem and re-examine your solution and see if there is another way to attack it.  For instance, is it viable to create your own UIView subclass so that you have more precision in responding to touch events, etc.?

Comment: I see. I thought iOS was more flexible when it comes to these "layers of views". But thanks for your help Paul!